# Get table column number after worksheet change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the column number of the table that i am working in but when i type `Target.column` it counts the columns from column A and not the start of the table.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim Table5 As ListObject

Set Table5 = Range("Table5").ListObject

Debug.Print "Something changed in cell " & Target.Column
t = Target.Column


For i = 1 To Table5.ListRows.Count

Next i

End Sub
```

Is there a way to do this without using `offset` if possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything with.   {table}.listcolumns.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to get the cell column relative to the table (`ListObject`)

```
Public Function GetCellColumn(ByVal myTable As ListObject, ByVal cell As Range) As Long
    GetCellColumn = cell.column - myTable.HeaderRowRange.column + 1
End Function
```

Let me know this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, i tweaked it a bit for my code and it works fine. Thank You